# Cannot get NodeJS Vue app to run on Windows due to Vue CLI Service

Tags: node.js, windows, vue.js, vue-cli

I cannot get a codebase to run on Windows 11. It works without any issues on MacOS and Ubuntu, as long as the Node version (14.15.5) is correct. Also works in production running on Heroku.

Judging by the console outputs, it seems the Node server starts successfully, connects to MongoDB, connects to Redis. So as far as I can tell, it's something to do with Vue or Vue CLI. The version of Vue in use is 2.6.12.

Error is triggered at `vue cli service serve`. Node version is correct. Tried to install Vue CLI globally too (using npm). What could be causing this?

###### Error logs:

[image]

###### Vue package.json:

```json
    {
      "name": "frontend",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
        "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer --port 4200 dist/stats.json"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document": "^18.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue": "^1.0.3",
        "@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs": "^3.3.2",
        "@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs-pro": "^3.7.1",
        "@johmun/vue-tags-input": "^2.1.0",
        "@vue/composition-api": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
        "autolinker": "^3.14.2",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "core-js": "^3.8.2",
        "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
        "detectrtc": "^1.4.1",
        "gsap": "^3.6.0",
        "imagekit-javascript": "^1.5.2",
        "imagekitio-vue": "^1.0.9",
        "ismobilejs": "^1.1.1",
        "just-detect-adblock": "^1.1.0",
        "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
        "maxlength-contenteditable": "^1.0.1",
        "socket.io-client": "^4.5.2",
        "timeme.js": "^2.1.0",
        "twilio-video": "^2.18.3",
        "v-hotkey": "^0.8.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-color": "^2.8.1",
        "vue-gtag": "^1.16.1",
        "vue-i18n": "^8.22.4",
        "vue-infinite-loading": "^2.4.5",
        "vue-router": "^3.4.9",
        "vue-select": "^3.18.3",
        "vue-smooth-dnd": "^0.8.1",
        "vue-vimeo-player": "^0.2.2",
        "vue-window-size": "^1.0.3",
        "vue-youtube": "^1.4.0",
        "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.6.2",
        "vuex": "^3.6.0",
        "webrtc-adapter-test": "^0.2.10"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.3.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.3.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~4.3.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "dotenv-webpack": "^5.1.0",
        "eslint": "^6.7.2",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "sass-loader": "^9.0.3",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.4.0"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "root": true,
        "env": {
          "node": true
        },
        "extends": [
          "plugin:vue/essential",
          "eslint:recommended"
        ],
        "parserOptions": {
          "parser": "babel-eslint"
        },
        "rules": {}
      },
      "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions",
        "not dead"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Did you run `npm install` in the vue project directory?

Comment: Yup, first ran `npm install` on the Node app package.json and then `npm install npm install --only=dev npm run build` on the Vue project directory.

Comment: Maybe the NODE_ENV variable is set to production. I don’t know if the —only flag is working. Try use `npm install --production=false` and then `npm run build` in the vue directory.

Comment: Seems --production=false didn't change the outcome, however.. ended up taking the risk of deleting package-lock.json and did npm install again and got it working. Not sure what it didn't like about the existing package-lock.json. A cleaner way to solve it would certainly be desirable.